# Firebase Database returns null value

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm selecting in item from a list (this list contains items from other users), and from this I'm generating a unique ID by combing the current user's ID with the ID of the user who posted the item in the list.

I then pass that ID through into a viewmodel and use it to try and retrieve a chat room created with the ID. However when im coming into the viewmodel, my snapshot below returns a null value. It's definitely referencing the right place in firebase database as the key in my log is the unique ID i created earlier,

Does anyone know why my value would be null even when I can see in my database it isn't null?

```
    chatRoomId?.let { chatRoomId ->

      firebaseDatabase.child("chat_rooms").child(chatRoomId)
           .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

               override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                   Log.d("snapshot", snapshot.toString())
                   val list = snapshot.children.map {
                       it.getValue(ChatMessage::class.java)
                   }
               }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "returns null value"? Nothing in your code seems to return anything as far as I can see.

Comment: Is this line `Log.d("snapshot", snapshot.toString())` printing null? Have you tried to use a hard coded value instead of  `chatRoomId`? Do you get the same result?

Comment: add your view-model class to your question